# How to read Android switch widget

Tags: switch-statement, android-widget

I added an andriod switch widget to my graphic.xml file in andriod,  and it moves and changes color so the widget works, but I dont know how to read the value,  it is on/off switch so I would expect off=0 and on=1   however when I look at the switch.java file I do not see and GetSwitchValue or SetSwitchValue type method in this library.  how do I actually read the value?

Answer (score 1):

You can set setOnCheckedChangeListener as following:

```
((Switch)findViewById(R.id.switchId)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
              @Override
              public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

              }
            });
```

Everytime switch is toggled, isChecked parameter contains the updated value.Based on the isChecked boolean 0/1 can be returned.